# Core Data: How to design a model for categories with subcategories

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am building UITableView with a list of Categories and also I added a button to add a "new category" on NavigationBar. So when I select an item of categories to reveal subcategories list on UITableView on next screen (something like Master-Detail screen) and also on that second screen that I can add another sub-category to this list. Almost like folder-directory or tree structure example. So I need to try to design a CoreData model. I don't have a really good example how to do that in CoreData. Any suggestion appreciated.

```
Category 1  >  -- SubCategory 1.1   
               -- SubCategory 1.2 -------> -- SubCategory 1.2.1 
                                           -- SubCategory 1.2.2  --->  -- SubCategory 1.2.2.1   
               -- SubCategory 1.3


Category 2  >  -- SubCategory 2.1

Category 3
```